# Getting Task Rejection Error in Threadpool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am Continuously getting task rejection error, even though it is completing the task successfully.

> 2018-03-27 05:57:37,518 454935266 [task-scheduler-5] ERROR o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@75a34d52[Running, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 490575051]] did not accept task: org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1@55cd80f5

This job just look for new entry in a Directory once it gets it will process it.
Also i dont know why its showing the Queued tasks as 1000, because that much file is not getting generated.

Comment: Do you have any other code in your Spring app, that is being run using @Async annotation? The tip is: you may be using the same small thread pool for your entire app, not only this "Directory" stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your `queueCapacity`, for example:

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(6);
executor.setQueueCapacity(5000); // <-- setting the queueCapacity
```

Comment: Could you please provide us some information, what you've changed in the code and how you fixed the issue?